# Npgsql LISTEN Thread Crashing Server

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, npgsql

I have a long running PostgreSQL function. For simplicity, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_function()
RETURNS void
AS
$$
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify('channel1', 'pg_function() started.');

    PERFORM pg_sleep(5);------PERFORM task1();-----------------------------------------
    PERFORM pg_notify('channel1', 'Task1 payload.');

    PERFORM pg_sleep(5);------PERFORM task2();-----------------------------------------
    PERFORM pg_notify('channel1', 'Task2 payload.');    

    PERFORM pg_sleep(5);------PERFORM task3();-----------------------------------------
    PERFORM pg_notify('channel1', 'Task3 payload.');    

    PERFORM pg_notify('channel1', 'pg_function() completed.');
END;
$$
LANGUAGE "plpgsql";
```

On C#, I have:

```
public bool listening;
public void PgFunction()
{
    this.listening = true;

    ThreadStart listenerStart = delegate
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            connection.Notification += Listen;

            using (NpgsqlCommand listenChannel1 = new NpgsqlCommand("LISTEN channel1;", connection))
            {
                listenChannel1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            while (this.listening)
            {
                using (NpgsqlCommand pollingCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT 0;", connection))
                {
                    pollingCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
    };

    Thread listenerThread = new Thread(listenerStart) { IsBackground = false };
    listenerThread.Start();

    ThreadStart pgFunctionThreadStart = () => ExecuteNonQuery(new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT pg_function();"));

    pgFunctionThreadStart += () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.listening = false;
    };

    Thread pgFunctionThread = new Thread(pgFunctionThreadStart) { IsBackground = true };
    pgFunctionThread.Start();
}

private void Listen(object sender, NpgsqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    string payload = e.AdditionalInformation;
    //SignalR stuff here
}
```

When I run the program debugging, this code works okay. But when it is tested on IIS server or browsed with Visual Studio 2013 integrated IIS, the application crashes. Since I have very little knowledge of tasks and threads in C#, I would like to know what I am doing wrong here? Please advise.

Edit

Upon debugging it again, I came with a NpgsqlException, which happens to happen once in a while:

> ```
> Additional information: Cannot write to a BufferedStream while the read buffer is not empty if 
> the underlying stream is not seekable. Ensure that the stream underlying this BufferedStream 
> can seek or avoid interleaving read and write operations on this BufferedStream.
> ```

Comment: Can't you use pollingCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() ?

Comment: Where the NpgsqlConnection comes from in the line: ThreadStart pgFunctionThreadStart = () => ExecuteNonQuery(new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT pg_function();")); ?  Also, you should try to use the synchronous notification feature. It will free you from having to make any pooling. Just add SyncNotification=true in your connection string. Check out our user manual for more information: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/wiki/User-Manual#working-with-notifications I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm asking about the connection above because I think you may be using the same connection with 2 or more threads and NpgsqlConnection isn't thread safe.